# Как из одного конструктора вызвать другой конструктор в C++?

Tags: c++

Как из одного конструктора вызвать другой конструктор в C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В С++03 это никак нельзя сделать.

Answer (score 6):

Начиная с С++11, можно вызывать один конструктор из другого, это называется "делегирующие конструкторы" (delegating constructors)

```
struct X {
   X(int a, int b) { std::cout << a+b; }
   X(int b) : X(1, b) {}
   X() : X(20) {}
};

X x; // X::X() вызывает X::X(int), который вызывает X::X(int, int)
```

При этом одновременно с вызовом другого конструктора нельзя вызывать конструкторы членов класса, например:

```
struct B {
  B() : x(1) {}
  B(int x_) : B(), x(x_) {} // ОШИБКА: нельзя одновременно вызвать B() и x()
  int x;
};
```

Как только был вызван один из конструкторов, объект считается полностью сконструированным, по этому исключение из вызывающего конструктора приведет к вызову деструктора класса:

```
struct C {
  C(const char*) { throw 1; }

  C() {}
  C(int) : C() { throw 1; }

  ~C() { std::cout << "~C\n"; }
};

int main() {
  try {
    C c(""); // ничего не будет напечатано, деструктор не будет вызван
  } catch (...) {}

  try {
    C c(1); // будет напечатано "~C"
  } catch (...) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо продублировать код в различных конструкторах одного объекта - лучше его вынести в отдельную ф-цию, которая будет делать всю черновую работу. И вызывать эту ф-цию из конструкторов.

Answer (score 0):

а что хотел конкретно автор вопроса может быть так?

```
  class c1
    {
    public:
        c1();
        c1(int i){printf("\nint ca()");}
        c1(float i,int c){printf("\nfloat ca()");}
    };

    class test
    {
    c1 c;
    public:

        test():c(10,4){printf("test\n");}
            ~test() {printf("\n~test!!!!");}
    };
    int main()
    {
        test a;

    }
```